# ros_control on embedded linux / rosserial

Tags: rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

is there any know way to make the c++ api described in the ros_control tutorials

(https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control/wiki/hardware_interface)

(http://wiki.ros.org/ros_control/Tutorials/Loading%20and%20starting%20controllers%20through%20service%20calls)

(http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_control)

work on a ROS Node, that runs on an embedded linux client?

In my case, I need a working solution for ros_control to work with a Lego Mindstorm EV3 running embedded linux. The EV3 communicates with a central PC over rosserial (rosserial_embeddedlinux) using WiFi / Bluetooth. I am already able to publish joint_state_msgs from the EV3, but I don't see any chances to get ros_control running.

Thanks for your thoughts!

best regards
psei

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259748/ros_control-on-embedded-linux-/-rosserial/) by [psei](https://answers.ros.org/users/6031/psei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2017-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosserial only allows to publish and receive ROS messages on a non-ROS system.

To run `ros_control` nodes, you will need a complete ROS system on the computer.

---

Originally posted by [rreignier](https://answers.ros.org/users/21983/rreignier/) with karma: 544 on 2017-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0